# how to get the difference of time between two timezones along with day light saving

Tags: c#

I need to get the difference between two time zones dynamically based on the user's profile.

Suppose if I am user A and today my profile is in MST time zone which is source time zone and my destination time zone is in PST time zone, then I need to get the difference of hrs of both MST and PST. Let us assume 3 hrs is the difference then I need to get the difference of these three hrs.

At the same time another user B may be in in CST time zone which is source time zone and the destination time zone is in HST time zone, then I need to get the difference of hrs of both CST and HST.Let us assume 1 hr is the difference then I need to get the difference of this one hr.

***If 'N' no of users are using the application and if they are in daylight saving then time zone calculation should be done based on daylight saving if they don't have day light saving the time zone calculation should be done without considering day light.***

How can I implement this? Can anybody help me out as I am new to this.

Comment: Difference in offset for what exact instant in time? It will change over time - because PST and MST aren't actually time zones, they're sort of "part of the time zones". A user would actually be in a time zone with an IANA ID of something like America/Los_Angeles, which would vary between PST and PDT. Your paragraph in bold is also unclear to me - what is the use of N here? And what if the target time zone is not in DST but the source zone is for the instant in question? (For example, America/Los_Angeles is currently observing DST, but Europe/London isn't.)

Comment: If you have full control on your application evaluate utc force all requests and responses in utc and let the client decide

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel: That's not always appropriate. For example, if a user wants to schedule a meeting for "9am every Monday" you can't specify a UTC value for that - it depends on the user's time zone. UTC is great for representing an *instant* in time that's independent of time zone, but in many cases the user's zone very much matters.

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel: Another example, *not* for a recurrent event: scheduling a single event in the future. You may *think* you know the UTC instant at which the event starts based on the user's time zone, but what if those time zone rules change? Morocco is a great recent example of this - any software that was storing UTC calculated before the recent rule changes but for a value *after* the rule changes would now have the wrong local time.

Comment: “Can anybody help me?” is [not a useful question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/).

Comment: I would strongly advise against using abbreviations as far as possible. They're ambiguous, don't represent complete time zones, and are basically horrible :(

Comment: @JonSkeet "time zone rules change" is the most unpredictable thing when dealing with DateTime and even you save a scheduler with user time zone your application may get wrong if you are not aware of the rule changes so this may need a full synchronization with the system or third-party service that has all the rules?

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel: IMO you should save the information you actually know, e.g. "user time zone ID and their local time". And then you need to keep an eye on when time zone rules are change and make your application able to cope with that. (For example, Noda Time provides a URL you can check for the latest time zone data, which can then be downloaded and used dynamically.)

Comment: @JonSkeet AFAK  when dealing with globalization the recommended practice is to store in Iso8601 isn't?

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel: ISO-8601 specifies a text format, which is a different aspect really. (And it doesn't have anywhere that specifies a time zone identifier, unfortunately. What it refers to as a "time zone" is really a UTC offset. They're not the same at all.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with that and what I have done when I have to work on global context is to store Iso8601 and the time zone id but not local time. is there any missed case that won't work when doing this?

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel: It's unclear what you mean by "store ISO-8601". Again, that's *just a text format* it doesn't say anything about what data you're storing (UTC or not). If you mean you've storing the UTC value, then yes, there are times that won't work. Suppose you want store an event which is meant to be "In Paris at 9am local time, December 1st 2019." If you convert that to UTC using the *current* rules, then the value will be invalid if the rules have changed between now and then. (That's possible but uncertain at the moment.) The UTC value may no longer represent 9am in Paris.

Answer (score 1):

This mechanism has worked for me for years. There is a registry key that Windows uses to maintain the time zone info of the local machine. I can't remember the version, however, a few years back .NET wrapped reading the time zone info into TimeZoneInfo objects, prior to that you had to write a wrapper yourself. The psuedo below shows the general usage. The basic tenants are:

```
1. Each client receives the time from the DB or other Layer as UTC. (all datetimes saved as UTC)
2. Using the client profile, convert the UTC DateTime value to the client's local value.
3. Display the date and do date math in the user's local time.
4. Before sending the time to the DB or another layer with different TZ convert back to UTC.
```

This should keep your date logic sound.

```
string userTimeZone = GetUsersTimeZone();
DateTime timeReadFromDBOrSomewhereInUTC = GetSomeDateTimeInUTC();


DateTime timeInUsersTimeZone = FromUTCToSpecificTimeZone(userTimeZone ,timeReadFromDBOrSomewhereInUTC );

edtTimeForAppointment.Text = timeInUsersTimeZone.ToString();

timeInUsersTimeZone.AddHours(2);

DateTime timeConvertedToUTCToSaveToDB = FromSpecificTimeZoneToUTC(userTimeZone,timeInUsersTimeZone);
```

Here is an example of two functions using TimeZoneInfo.

```
public static DateTime FromSpecificTimeZoneToUTC(TimeZoneInfo fromZone, DateTime specificTimeZoneDateTime)
{
    DateTime temp = DateTime.SpecifyKind(specificTimeZoneDateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(temp, fromZone);
}

public static DateTime FromUTCToSpecificTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo toZone, System.DateTime UTCTimeZoneDateTime)
{           
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UTCTimeZoneDateTime, toZone);
}
```

If you just need the offset of a `DateTime` between two timrzones then the function below may prove useful.

```
public static TimeSpan GetTimeZoneOffsetDifference(TimeZoneInfo oldZone, TimeZoneInfo newZone)
{           
    var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    TimeSpan oldOffset = oldZone.GetUtcOffset(now);
    TimeSpan newOffset = newZone.GetUtcOffset(now);
    TimeSpan difference = oldOffset - newOffset;
    return difference;
}
```

Comment: Your point 1 is fundamentally broken if you're storing future date/time values which have a user intention of a specific *local* time. The time zone rules may change between the time when you convert the original value to UTC and the time when you convert the UTC back to the local time - so you may not end up with what the user asked for.

Comment: I think UTC is just an arbitrary zone used to simplify time zone math. Since UTC does not change with the season and the offset is 0, I guess it was chosen as the best fit zone to normalize time around.

Comment: The time zone of the user saving the data. For example, the possible changes either next year or in a couple of years to abolish DST in Europe. If you convert (say) a local time of 9am in Paris on November 10th 2022 to UTC *now*, that instant in time may well not be 9am in Paris by the time November 10th 2022 rolls around. If the user specified 9am and then later your application shows 8am, I'd classify that as a bug. If instead you save the data you were actually *given*, then you can apply the known time zone rules at any point in time.

Comment: Doesn't the same thing happen when there is a lag in dst between two time zones. If I save a record in local time Amsterdam and view it in the US, there will be about a two week lag in which the time is an hour off from what was intended, however, this is still following the time zone conversion rules set fourth. Two weeks later the time will catch up, the difference is the two week lag in offset adherence.

Comment: Sorry, Jon, I did not purposely delete my comment that you replied on. I can't figure out how to get it back :(

Comment: No problem in terms of deletion. But no, the same thing doesn't happen when the rules don't actually change but take effect at different times. When I say "the rules change" I don't mean "Paris goes into DST" or "Paris falls back from DST" I mean "version x of the rules say that Paris will fall back from DST on (say) October 27th 2020, but version x+1 of the rules say that the Paris offset stays the same from March 29th 2020 until the end of time". (Morocco very recently had such a change of rules, with *very* little warning time.)

Comment: (The exact situation in Europe is still to be decided. It could be 2019, it could be delayed for a couple of years. But it's very likely that European countries will effectively reset their standard time to be one hour later than now, and stop observing DST transitions. See https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-may-scrap-dst.html.)

Comment: I guess the same thing would happen if a country decides to stop following DST altogether. That is an interesting read BTW. Would you not term these edge cases and make appropriate updates to data when the time arises? I dont feel like this is something very easy to defensively program against.

Comment: I wouldn't call "all of Europe" an edge case, no. If the rules *do* change for 2019, I think it's highly likely that many users are creating records with post-rule-change dates in many applications already. And sure, it's not "very easy" to code against, but it's also far from impossible. I've already explained how to do it: you don't normalize to UTC other than as an optimization (which can be recalculated when the rules change). The canonical data is what the user gives you: their local time and time zone.

Comment: I think that moving the point in which a TZ adheres DST would not be that big of a deal, especially if the web servers' TZ info patched. However, big problems would arise if a TZ was suddenly changed from a UTC-3 offset to a UTC-5, at that point ,the difference could not just be explained by the observance/non-observance of DST. As far as storing the date in event locale, how would you handle the situation in which multiple observers in different time zones would like to observe a non-local event in their local time? Using UTC, you would simply convert once from utc to each observers time.

Comment: "I think that moving the point in which a TZ adheres DST would not be that big of a deal" - it is if you've already converted the original data into UTC. "As far as storing the date in event locale, how would you handle the situation in which multiple observers in different time zones would like to observe a non-local event in their local time?" If UTC is the original data, that's fine. Otherwise, you can always convert from one time zone to another. The important thing is to avoid losing information, which "always convert to UTC" does.

Comment: It is still safe to save store dates/times in their UTC representation for systems that process daily transactions, correct? If I am reading you correctly, your are saying information can be lost when storing future facing dates in UTC representation as opposed to the local TZ.

Comment: If you're storing timestamps in the past or *very* near future - so near that you're confident you will never encounter a situation where your time zone data at the point of recording gives a different result to the time zone data at the time itself, then sure. It's worth being aware that sometimes time zone changes can come with very little notice, and that updates can take a long time to reach your code, depending on various things such as the platform you're using.

Comment: So it may well be that for your code, you're fine - but it's worth being very aware that blanket guidance of "normalize to UTC" will not work properly for all applications by any means, despite that guidance being very common in the industry :(

Answer (score 0):

We have handled this in the past using the `DateTimeOffset` parsed either

- JavaScript inserting the local time of the user during form submission
- User profile in which we save the preferred timezone offset in minutes

We have stored the offset as `SMALLINT` instead of alternatives because it is so easy to work with `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` and so we can support time zones not just an hour offset (like India being UTC+5:30).

With the DateTimeOffset stored in the database with the exact UTC offset, we've been able to report as we prefer (by UTC or translating to a preferred timezone) or show audit/data tables meeting our requirements.

With that said, I imagine there are better and many other approaches.

Comment: "User profile in which we save the preferred timezone offset in minutes" - how does that work for time zones which don't have a fixed offset, but observe DST? What about changes to time zone rules?

Comment: Good point - definitely a gap. The JavaScript method is used for data input mostly, and then we use the profile for rendering on page (which has worked fine given the controlled user base we have that deployed for). However, seems like the easiest method could be just to store everything in UTC, then let front-end JavaScript/framework adjust based on local time. as needed.

Comment: Please read my comments on the other answer and the question. Normalizing to UTC loses information, which can definitely be problematic if the value is in the future.